# Trying to write to buffer using %n causes segfault but read using %p doesn't

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I have exploitable `c` code which takes user input. I am able to print out contents of the stack using `%10$p` which prints out the 10th value stored on the stack. However when I try to run the same program but with `%10$n` it segfaults. Which does not make sense. Segfaults means I am trying to access memory that does not belong to me. However, this memory does 'belong to me' since I can print it out. Why does this happen?

Unfortunately, I cannot postcode for it because it is for an assignment. So I have to keep this question abstract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%10$n` means write the number of characters printed to the address **pointed** to by the 10th element on the stack, not the actual 10th element of the stack. This means that if the 10th element doesn't point to valid, writable memory, which it likely doesn't, then you will segfault upon trying to write to it.